# access AWS Keyspace from springboot application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-keyspaces

I am trying to doa POC to see how we can connect AWS Keyspace from a springboot application. I running it from my local desktop.

I am using IAM user accesskey/secret and using datastax and aws java sdk dependency.

**application.properties**

```
aws.accessKey=ACCESS_KEY
aws.secretKey=SECRET_KEY
aws.region=us-east-2
aws.keyspace.endPoint=cassandra.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
aws.keyspace.name=test_keyspace
```

I have also created a bean of AmazonKeyspace using BasicAWSCredentials and AmazonKeyspaceClientBuilder using the above properties. I have doubt about this endpoint, if this is correct or not

but when I am running the application, it's failing with **AllNodesFailedException**.
Can you please let me know how to resolve this issue ? I am not sure if I missing something for this.

Answer (score 1):

To work with Keyspace in a Java project, it's recommended that you use [software.amazon.awssdk.services.keyspaces.KeyspacesClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/keyspaces/KeyspacesClient.html), which is AWS SDK for V2. AWS Java V1 is on the path to deprecation:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-end-of-support-for-aws-sdk-for-java-v1-x-on-december-31-2025/

You need to do a few steps:

1. Create an **application.conf** file that references the JKS file. See below.
2. You must create a Cassandra Java client driver (JKS) file. This file is a secure file format used to hold certificate information for Java applications. This is required to make a connection to Amazon Keyspaces. For more information, see the following documentation topic:   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/using_java_driver.html.

You will need that **application.conf** file. Here is the contents. Notice it references the **JKS** file.

```
datastax-java-driver {
            basic.contact-points = ["cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9142"]
            basic.load-balancing-policy {
                class = DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy
                local-datacenter = us-east-1
                slow-replica-avoidance = false
            }
            advanced {
                auth-provider = {
                    class = software.aws.mcs.auth.SigV4AuthProvider
                    aws-region = us-east-1
                }
                ssl-engine-factory {
                    class = DefaultSslEngineFactory
                    truststore-path = "C:\\Users\\scmacdon\\KeyspaceCert\\cassandra_truststore.jks"
                    truststore-password = "11xxxxxxxx"
                    hostname-validation = false
                }
            }
        }
```

To work with **KeyspacesClient** and the required **CqlSession** object, use the code below.

```
 String configFilePath = "C:\\AWS\\application.conf";
    Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
    KeyspacesClient keyClient = KeyspacesClient.builder()
        .region(region)
        .build();
    
   DriverConfigLoader loader = DriverConfigLoader.fromFile(new File(configFilePath));
   CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder()
       .withConfigLoader(loader)
       .build();
```

To handle creds, see the Java V2 dev guide here: [Default credentials provider chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-chain.html).

You will also need a **movies.jso**n file for the full example. You can find that here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/resources/sample_files

To run the full example in Java V2, run this code. This will get your familiar with the V2 KeyspacesClient.

See:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/keyspaces/src/main/java/com/example/keyspace/ScenarioKeyspaces.java

Note this example is too big to post here.

I just ran this and it works...

[image]

Comment: I have some doubts, when we are using sdk v2 still we need the application.conf ? is there any way we can achieve this with this file and run some basic CRUD operation ?

Comment: You need application.conf  and you need to reference the Driver File in that as shown in my answer. Once you setup the application.conf and the Driver File, you can create a KeyspacesClient object and perform CRUD operations. In the example, you perform standard database CRUD operations.

Comment: Follow the doc topic to create the driver file -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/using_java_driver.html

Comment: I am still facing some issue so will work on those item, but I have few more doubts. for example if our application is hosted in Openshift rosa can we use a service role to connect Keyspace ? if yes how we can do this any example or documentation we have ? Also, in this case how we can test our application from local desktop ? sorry we have new to this so have not much how to achieve this.

Comment: I have never tried hosting on that platform. Yes, you can test your code from Local Desktop, I test all code in IntelliJ on local desktop,

Comment: okay I got that I can test it from the above code, but looking for some documentation on how to use service role to make any connection.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/ec2-iam-roles.html

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working for me. it is failing with the same error

Comment: Find me on Linked in (see profile) and I can get you up and running

Comment: I sent you a connection request